# Can I let Albert ignore certain files/folders?

Tags: albert

The files extension indexes a huge amount of files I actually never need. Can I tell albert to ignore particular files and subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to gitignores you can create a file called `.albertignore` in the folder that contains the files you want to ignore. Fill it with the filenames you want to ignore one per line. The ignores supports [wildcard matching](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#wildcard-matching). For details see the [documentation of the files extesion](https://github.com/albertlauncher/plugins/blob/master/files/README.md#file-filters--ignore-files).

An example ignore file:

```
# Ignore eclipse dir
/workspace

# Ignore git projects
/git/*

# Include albert repos though
!/git/albert
!/git/aur-albert

# However in the albert repo don't index source files
/git/albert/**.cpp

# General ignores
node_modules
bower_components
```

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>